# Is there a way to reset between-level skill progression without going to jail?

Tags: the-elder-scrolls-v-skyrim

[Serving one's sentence](http://www.uesp.net/wiki/Skyrim:Jail#Serving_Your_Sentence), for crimes, results in loss of "progress towards one or more [skill](http://www.uesp.net/wiki/Skyrim:Skills) level advancements; the longer your sentence, the more skills so affected. The maximum sentence is seven days; if you serve seven days, your skill advancement will be cleared for every skill."

It's not that the skill's level is set back to the minimum value or 1 or 0 or anything like that, but the XP progress from the current level to attain the next skill level will be reset. How do I get such an effect without serving a sentence?

Comment: Out of curiosity, can I ask why?

Comment: In games where it is possible, I want to have a perfect start. Part of my current definition of a perfect start is not having skills progression until I actually mean to grind the skills (in case I don't want the skill advancement for any reason). There is a glitch at the beginning of the game that gives me Sneak XP for no reason. I've had to (and still have to) meticulously check if I've gained Sneak XP each time I save. This is before I am unbound by either Ralof or Hadvar. Sneaking doesn't (or isn't supposed to) even gain Sneak XP at this point.

Comment: How very interesting. I believe that is probably caused by at some point where you are moving around outside of everybody's sightlines. (Or at least that's how I believe the mechanic works).

Comment: I think it's more a save glitch. I wonder if it has been patched in the unofficial patch(es).

Comment: You gain sneak by being outside the sightline WHILE 'sneaking' so if you don't want to gain Sneak skill, dont sneak.

Comment: I know, but I was getting Sneak XP even before being given movement control, and I'm pretty sure I didn't accidentally hit the sneak key or load in from a state of sneaking either. It's hard to get footage of it; it seems uncommon enough that I dread trying to reproduce it. At the point that I can reproduce it, there's probably no point in getting footage; I'd probably know by then what causes it. Considering how [I am perfectly familiar with how Sneak XP is earned](http://gaming.stackexchange.com/a/183435/46216), I would not accidentally sneak if I don't want any sneak XP.

Answer (score 2):

You cannot.  The only way to reset your skill progress without modifying the game via mods and/or console commands is to serve your jail sentence.

Answer (score 1):

Via console:
`player.advskill <skill> <`[base XP](http://www.uesp.net/wiki/Skyrim:Leveling#Skill_XP)`>` until next skill level (via trial & error), then
`player.setav <skill> <level>` back to original skill level.

I don't know how to prevent the resulting character level XP. The effect could be minimized by setting the skill level to the lowest before levelling it up (then setting it back to the original level).

To remove a resulting perk point, spend a perk point, then
`removeperk <perk ID>`.

> To find the perk ID code in-game, try `help <perkname> 4`.

> Quotation marks are required for queries of more than one word (e.g., help "ancient nord").

> For perk ID codes, see the page for the perk's corresponding skill, indexed at [Skills](http://www.uesp.net/wiki/Skyrim:Skills).
>
> Important note: To remove perks from an established tree, you will need to backtrack through the entire tree. Meaning, start from the top and work your way down. In perks with ranks, you will need to remove rank 5/5, then 4/5, etc. Also, using removeperk will only remove the perk. It will not refund the perk points.
>
> E.g., `player.removeperk 000babe8` will remove Barbarian rank 1/5.

http://www.uesp.net/wiki/Skyrim:Console